# Magento 2 : Uncollapse Summery On First Step Of Checkout Page

Tags: magento2, checkout, blocks, checkout-page

I need to uncollapse summery block on first step of checkout page.

Currently On first step (address) it's collapsed, then on next step it's uncollapsed.

I would like it to be also uncollapsed on first step of checkout page.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html and change (line number 8)

```
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active'}}">
```

to

```
<div class="block items-in-cart active" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': true}}">
```

and to override, create or edit requirejs-config.js file from below path:

```
app/code/Namespace/Mudule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
```

And place below code in requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Checkout/template/summary/cart-items.html': 
              'Namespace_Module/template/summary/cart-items.html'
        }
  }
};
```

Comment: welcome buddy !